# Understanding of Direct Product

Tags: linear-algebra

Given vector space $V_1$ and $V_2$ over $K$. We defie $V_1\times V_2$ in the usual way. One can also do it. In other direction, for that we need a claim of $V_1\times V_2$ in terms of $V_1$ and $V_2$.

First of all $V_1\times V_2$ contains copies of $V_1$ and $V_2$, namely $V_1\times\left\{0\right\}$ and $\left\{0\right\}\times V_2$. We also have

- $V_1\times\left\{0\right\}\cap\left\{ 0\right\} \times V_{2}=0$
- $V_{1}\times \left\{ 0\right\} +\left\{ 0\right\} \times V_{2}=V_{1}\times V_{2}$.

It is from my lecture notes. 
**can you give an example that it satisfies  $V_1\times\left\{0\right\}\cap\left\{ 0\right\} \times V_{2}=0$ and $V_{1}\times \left\{ 0\right\} +\left\{ 0\right\} \times V_{2}=V_{1}\times V_{2}$? Actually, what is the  $V_1\times\left\{0\right\}$? mean?**

Answer (score 0):

Suppose the intersection was non-trivial (there is a non-zero point in their intersection). Then, one of the two components is non-zero. Assume the left component is non-zero. We reach an issue because then that point is not in {$0$} $\times V_2$.

The second part is trivial if addition is done component wise: $(v_1, 0) + (0, v_2) = (v_1, v_2)$